# How to fix "Expecting end of line without line continuation"

Tags: pine-script

```
indicator("ema 18/20",overlay=true)
emaFast = input(defval=18)
emaSlow = input(defval=20)
longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.ema(close,18), ta.ema(close,20))
strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit (id= "ema 18/20", profit=0.01)
if (longCondition) == true
takeprofit= 0.3
```

I can not remove last line error, pine script shows:

> 'takeprofit' expecting end of line without line continuation

I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Three things.

1. You need to have 4 spaces or 1 tab after the `if`.
2. You cannot call functions like `strategy.entry` in indicator scripts. You should change this to a `strategy`.
3. `takeprofit` is defined in a local scope. You probably want to move that to the global scope by defining it outside of the if block. Then use the `:=` assignment operator to assign it a value in the if block.

Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("ema 18/20",overlay=true)
emaFast = input(defval=18)
emaSlow = input(defval=20)
longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.ema(close,18), ta.ema(close,20))
strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit (id= "ema 18/20", profit=0.01)
if (longCondition) == true
    takeprofit= 0.3
```